# Why does ejabberd_config do add_table_copy immediately after create_table?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, mnesia

Code:

```
mnesia:create_table(local_config,
    [{ram_copies, [node()]},
    {local_content, true},
    {attributes, record_info(fields, local_config)}]),
mnesia:add_table_copy(local_config, node(), ram_copies),
```

What's the purpose of this `add_table_copy` ?

I found `ejabberd_config` read configuration later with ETS api directly. Is it relevant with this redundant copy ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ejabberd is meant to run as a cluster. If this is the first node in the cluster to execute this code, then the table will be created. If this is *not* the first node, then the table is already created, but we want to make a local copy of the table on this node.

One of the two statements will essentially be a no-op, depending on when the nodes of the cluster execute.

Comment: {local_content, true} option makes this table [always one-node](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/Mnesia_chap5.html#id76369) (since only `[node()]` was given to copies). Since those are local options, each node in cluster will run this code and have own, not-shared table.

Comment: local_content means the table content is local, not the schema. Schema table is always replicated in ejabberd cluster, so I think nathanial's answer make sense, create_table will be a no-op at the second node.

Answer (score 1):

Mnesia is just wrapper around `ets` adding distribution, transactions, and few other features.  In this case we create table only on this node, without any distribution or dist storage.  So in the end we create only one `ets` table, only on local node.

But this does not guarantee any fault tolerance. If you look into how `ets` works you will see that each table is assigned to some process.  If process dies, all data disperse.  To protect our self's from this loss we create one more table, assigned to different process, that will act as backup for the firs one.

Comment: Yes, start a monitor process for ets table is a common practice, [link](http://steve.vinoski.net/blog/2011/03/23/dont-lose-your-ets-tables/), but I didn't see any code in ejabberd_config did it. thanks.

Comment: If there's a concern about fault tolerance, the solution is to persist on disk, not to have two in-memory copies.

Answer (score 0):

There is several implied question in a single one:

1. Why do we need to add a local copy after adding a table ?

ejabberd is design to run in cluster. Adding a local copy is required when starting ejabberd for the first time on second cluster node (and subsequent ones).

2. Is it relevant to create a Mnesia table if later the table is used using ETS ?

ETS is the underlying storage for Mnesia. If you really know what you are doing you can sometime manipulate data using direct access to ETS functions. This is possible for example for performance or convenience reason, especially it the content for the table is local (no content cluster-wide synchronization).

3. Is it redundant to add table copy after table creation if content of the table is local ? It does not seems to involve other node.

It is not redundant. It is actually needed (for Mnesia schema management). If your remove the call to `mnesia:add_table_copy/3`, you will get issue in production during Mnesia database operations.